# Accessing values inside an object

Tags: swift, xcode, stripe-payments

When the user of the application selects a card, I want to be able to retrieve the user's `'stripeID'`, however whenever I print `paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption` I am able to see the data that I need, but cannot access it.

Language used: swift.

I am using stripe for the payment system in Swift, and I am also using the stripe UI to allow users to add their credit card information to the app.
your comments will be very helpful

The message I am receiving is:

> STPPaymentMethod: 0x28105c080; stripeId = pm_1GuuilCs27VSYM8G5UUd3q2S;
> auBECSDebit = (null); bacsDebit = (null); billingDetails =
> <STPPaymentMethodBillingDetails: 0x282b4d3c0; name = (null); phone =
> (null); email = (null); address = <STPPaymentMethodAddress:
> 0x281d2e3f0; line1 = (null); line2 = (null); city = (null); state =
> (null); postalCode = 6643; country = (null)>>; card =
> <STPPaymentMethodCard: 0x281affea0; brand = Mastercard; checks =
> <STPPaymentMethodCardChecks: 0x2831c9cb0; addressLine1Check: (null);
> addressPostalCodeCheck: pass; cvcCheck: pass>; country = US; expMonth
> = 2; expYear = 2054; funding = credit; last4 = 4444; fingerprint = TBj8N5wToO3eEbfK; threeDSecureUsage =
> <STPPaymentMethodThreeDSecureUsage: 0x283f38840; supported: YES>;
> wallet = (null)>; cardPresent = (null); created = 2020-06-17 06:26:04
> +0000; customerId = cus_HTrYPeMU1l0pcB; ideal = (null); fpx = (null); sepaDebit = (null); liveMode = NO; metadata = { }; type = card

Any comments or assistance you can provide on this issue would be a great help.

Comment: in order to make it work, I had to cast paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption as? STPPaymentMethod to get the striped.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this option should be performed in the backend,so you can list them or target the exact one.

Here how you retrieve an account: https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/retrieve?lang=node